# I need help getting my JavaScript file to work on wordpress through child theme?

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I asked this question on css-tricks but only got one response which I implemented in my child functions file , but its still not working, you can see the thread here : http://css-tricks.com/forums/topic/i-need-help-getting-my-javascript-file-to-work-on-wordpress-through-child-theme/#post-160138

Inside my wordpress page which you can see here towards the bottom : http://izaguirre.me/contact/ 
I have this in html :

```
<div id="myDiv">
These Are Radom Letters To Test The Connection Of the JAVA File DSFDFSFSDFF
</div>
```

And in my myscript.js file in my child theme the only code I have inside is this :

```
document.getElementById('myDiv').style.background = "black";
```

But I see no reflection of the JS working since there is no visible background change on the example I put at the end of the  izaguirre.me/contact/ page ?

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong but this is not a question...

Comment: My apologies if this does not look like a question, but it is, Matthias Lehming gave me the right answer even though I still have some questions on his response

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The js-file couldn't get loaded (404). You uploaded it to your child theme's folder `(http://izaguirre.me/wp-content/themes/selfy-child/myscript.js)`,

but the page actually tries to load it from the parent themes folder 
`(http://izaguirre.me/wp-content/themes/selfy/js/myscript.js)`.

Comment: YES Adding the myscript.js file to my parent themes js folder makes everything work perfectly, thank you! I just have a few questions , 1.) Why does this not work with the myscript.js file in my parent theme? Is there a way to change something to make it try to load the file in the child theme? ----- and 2.) Would keeping the myscript.js file in my parent theme mean that when I update the theme I will have to re-upload the myscript.js file from a backup since I assume it will be erased since its not part of the original theme files ?

Comment: Quick edit on question "1.) Why does this not work with the myscript.js file in my parent theme?" I mean Child theme *

Comment: The thing is, that you have to embed the right path in your template file. And as far as I know, if you update your theme, the complete folder will be replaced. So you should upload the JS-File to your child theme folder and also link it embed it (with the path to your child theme folder) in a template file, which is also in the child theme folder. Then, you should be safe with updates.

Comment: Hi Thank you again for helping me, when you say that I have to  embed the right path in my template file, what file name does this go by so I can locate it , are you speaking of the index.php file ? and if you are , are you saying that I should create an index.php file in my child theme and then add a script source line of code that includes "myscript.js" ? so to sum that up I should create an index.php file in my child theme and have the script source be the only line of code in it to link it to my JS file also in my child theme? Would I also have to change the functions php code again ?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to put after the

```
<div id="myDiv">
  These Are Radom Letters To Test The Connection Of the JAVA File DSFDFSFSDFF
</div>
```

this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById('myDiv').style.background = "black";
</script>
```

I think it will work.

Comment: Ok what you addded works but even though I sort of understand why it works its not a functional way because its like adding the Javascript only to the html in the wordpress and not needing the JS file in my child theme ? ( Im new so im assuming)